# I was trying to run yarn,but am getting this issue.Yarn is installed but cant even access the version

Tags: hadoop, cmd, environment-variables, hadoop-yarn, java-home

> yarn --version

```
The system cannot find the path specified.
Error: JAVA_HOME is incorrectly set.
       Please update C:\Users\shriy\Downloads\hadoop-3.1.0\etc\hadoop\hadoop-env.cmd
'-Dhadoop.log.dir' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
```

Answer (score 0):

Your java environment path must not contain space. The solution is as follows:

In the cmd line, charge the directory that contain the jdk (in my case C:\Program Files\Java\jdk1.8.0_73).
execute the following line "for %I in (.) do echo %~sI" to display the short name of your installed jdk (in my case C:\PROGRA~1\Java\JDK18~1.0_7)
in the file "hadoop-env.cmd", change the line "JAVA_HOME=%JAVA_HOME%" with "JAVA_HOME=C:\PROGRA~1\Java\JDK18~1.0_7".
run again the file "hadoop-env.cmd" and it will work correctly.